# Eclipse not opening frame window

Tags: java, eclipse, jframe

I ran this code in Eclipse Indigo, and no frame was opening as the output but when I ran the same code in BLUEJ it works properly and frame is opening. Plz tell me the bug.

Here is my code:

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame 
{

 void MainFrame()
{
    setTitle("Square's Root Finder");
    setSize(350,100);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLookAndFeel();
    setVisible(true);
    JButton but1 = new JButton("Calculate");
    JLabel label1= new JLabel("Enter the number:");
    JTextField t = new JTextField();
    add(but1);
    add(label1);
    add(t);


}
 private void setLookAndFeel() {
      try {
      UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
      "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
      } catch (Exception exc) {
      // ignore error
      }
      }

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    MainFrame newFrame = new MainFrame();

}

      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bug is in this line:

```
 void MainFrame()
```

Change it to:

```
public MainFrame()
```

Constuctors should not have return type as per [JAVA documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

> Constructor declarations look like method declarations—except that they use the name of the class  **and have no return type.**